# why can't I change my aws rds oracle 'public access' to 'yes'?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just created an aws account. When I try to create an rds instance, I am unable to change the 'public accessibiity' to yes, even after the instance is created. I tried diferent data bases, and the problem continues. Can someone tell me what is going on?

[This is what I find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1aox.png)

[This is what I find before and after creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1aox.png)

Comment: Have you tried clearing browser cache/incognito?

Comment: Your two screenshots are same. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Marcin, that was not intentional, I had difficulty understanding how to add a picture. Thanks for the help guys, I solved it already. The adblock was kind of blocking the visibility of the available options.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change this via the AWS Management console, try using the AWS RDS API to modify an RDS instance database by changing it to allow public access. You can create a **ModifyDbInstanceRequest** object and set **publiclyAccessible** to true.

```
public static void updateIntance(RdsClient rdsClient, String dbInstanceIdentifier, String masterUserPassword) {

        try {
            
            ModifyDbInstanceRequest modifyDbInstanceRequest = ModifyDbInstanceRequest.builder()
                    .dbInstanceIdentifier(dbInstanceIdentifier)
                    .publiclyAccessible(true)
                    .masterUserPassword(masterUserPassword)
                    .build();

            ModifyDbInstanceResponse instanceResponse = rdsClient.modifyDBInstance(modifyDbInstanceRequest);
            System.out.print("The ARN of the modified database is: " +instanceResponse.dbInstance().dbInstanceArn());

        } catch (RdsException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I solved it already. it was the adblock.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it already. The adblock was kind of blocking the visibility of the available options. Thanks for the help!